# How can one configure Windows 10 so that a given process never uses a given Wi-Fi network?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I don't want a process (e.g., the Backblaze backup program) to ever use Internet if I am connected to a given Wi-Fi network (e.g., my Android hotspot). How can I do that? I use Windows 10. I still want the process to be able to use other Internet networks when I am connected to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't have that ability.

The most you can do is add a firewall rule to block that program when you
are on a network connection that is defined as public:

- Start the Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security
- Click "Outbound Rules"
- Click on the right "New Rule..."
- Set "Rule Type" to `Program` and click Next
- Set "This program path" to the program to block and click Next
- Set "Action" to "Block the connection", and click Next
- Set "Profile" to "Public" only and click Next
- Give the rule a descriptive name and click Finish.

You will have to insure that this Wi-Fi network is defined as Public.

Reference :
[Make a Wi-Fi network public or private in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d).

Comment: You can also add a shortcut to enable and to disable the Firewall Rule: save two .bat files with `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="StopBackblaze" new enable=no` ,and with `yes` at end, and make shortcuts to them, to respectively disable and enable the rule. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/netsh-advfirewall-firewall-control-firewall-behavior